# How to use diazo and editskiswitcher together

Tags: diazo

I want to use a diazo theme based on no theme(!). i.e. no sunburst, not classical plone. And at the same time to use e.g. Sunburst for admin purposes. Maybe via editskiswitcher. Is it possible?

It seems that diazo uses the base theme both for the active theme and for the unthemed hostnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Plone Site is in `192.168.45.131` and you have following entry in your hosts file:

```
192.168.45.131    192.168.45.131-unthemed
```

Create a Plone Site (e.g. "Plone")

`http://192.168.45.131:8080/Plone/portal_quickinstaller/manage_installProductsForm`

```
  [x] Collective Skin Switcher      3.1
  [x] Diazo theme support       1.1.1
  [Install]
```

`http://192.168.45.131:8080/Plone/portal_properties/editskin_switcher/manage_propertiesForm`

```
 edit_skin=Sunburst Theme
 switch_skin_action=based on specific domains
 specific_domains=http://192.168.45.131-unthemed:8080
```

`http://192.168.45.131:8080/Plone/@@theming-controlpanel`

```
  (Create and) activate a diazo_theme
```

`http://192.168.45.131:8080/Plone/++theme++diazo_theme/@@theming-controlpanel-mapper`

```
  add the following to rules.xml
    <after css:theme-children="body" css:content-children="body" />
    [Save File]
```

`http://192.168.45.131:8080/Plone/@@theming-controlpanel`

```
  Advanced settings
    Unthemed host names=192.168.45.131-unthemed
    Theme base=(Unstyled)
    [ ] Use popup overlays for simple forms
        # this also disables/enables popup overlays on unthemed host names
```

`http://192.168.45.131:8080/Plone` will show your diazo theme

`http://192.168.45.131-unthemed:8080/Plone` will show Plone's Sunburst Theme