# How to use two different themes depending on the url with diazo?

Tags: plone, diazo

I need a solution that meets following requirements:

1. use a diazo theme based on unstyled(!), Theme base (i.e. "Plone Default") with the URL diazotheme.domain.com
2. use "Sunburst Theme" (or any other Plone Theme) with the URL "sunburst.domain.com"

It seems that diazo not only uses the Base Theme for the diazo theme but also for the "Unthemed host names". Setting the Base Theme in diazo's "@@theming-controlpanel" actually changes the Default skin of the Site.

I've posted a solution using diazo in combination with editskinswitcher: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23130398/1659599. I'd like to know whether this is possible without using editskinswitcher.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [collective.behavior.localdiazo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.behavior.localdiazo) package.

You can see it in action in http://www.cfa.org.br/rba site, which has a different theme from http://www.cfa.org.br/ main site.

RBA is an instance of Microsite, a Dexterity-based content type defined in [sc.microsite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sc.microsite).

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to switch plone skin? Or would it be enough to change the diazo theme, using the same (more or less neutral) plone skin?

I use this approach to switch diazo rule set and index.html depending on the path. The two diazo themes uses different resources: images, styles, js, etc., and are very different.

My rules.xml - shortened:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules
    xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
    xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

    <!-- The theme for my "app" -->
    <rules if-path="/app_path /site/app_path">
        <theme href="index_app.html"/>
        <!-- rules for the specific path -->
    </rules>

    <!-- The default theme, used for standard Plone web pages -->
    <theme href="index.html" css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper" />

    <!-- Rules applying to a standard Plone web page -->
    <rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">
        <!-- rules for the rest of the site -->
    </rules>
</rules>
```

The same should be doable for domains using p.a.theming theme parameters: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.theming#theme-parameters

and using "Conditions based on arbitrary parameters" from http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/advanced.html

(replace the if-path with if="$host = 'domain'")

UNTESTED! :)

Comment: I can report that `if="$host = 'domain'"` works fine.  Just eight short years and you get your upvote, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

you'll definitely need a mechanism to activate different skins for the different parts of you site. editskinswitcher is one choice here.

you could also code your own traverser that applies the correct browserlayer and patches the portal_skins tool.

another approach is to allow skin selection in portal_skins and set the skin via a request variable.
the concept is outlined here: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/10311